# current date, year , month in react through function

Tags: reactjs

I am having one code

```
const currYear =() =>{

    var year = new Date.getFullYear();

        return year;

    }
```

`{this.currYear}` this is the way I am accessing it in my component but it is not displaying. I can do this in a different way but that works.

`{new Date.getFullYear()}` this is the direct javascript method to call rendering in the react js. And this way it is works.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with `{this.currYear()}`.

Comment: {this.currYear()}. this is a wrong syntax in react we cant call any functions with a round bracket :) thats a error.

Answer (score 1):

It is not displaying because you've declared it as a `const` **outside the class**. **If is declared outside of the class**, you need to refer **without** `this`.

Add as a method and then, trigger the function acessing with `this`.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    currYear(){
        let d = new Date();
        return d.getFullYear();
    }

    render(){
        return(<div>{this.currYear()}</div>)
    }
}
```

Comment: const is inside a class :)

Comment: yes your answer is correct, but only one change

function currYear() else react produce a error.

Comment: Yes, you can define a const variable inside the `render` method, but you can't declare inside the `class`.

If the arrow function is inside the `render` method, then you should refer without the `this` prefix, it is the principle of OOP.

Comment: @wontone_boys which kind of error? I've tested it here and its ok.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/jipxjn here this one...it should having function before the name

your code is correct.

one more thing if i want to put this function outside my current .js file i mean i will create one include js file which contains all my functions.

And through my function i will access this function

my method is
import sysFunction from "../SysFunctions/SysFunctions";

then access its function {this.currYear()} but that actually not working

Comment: @wontone_boys You need to declare this method outside the render() function to access with `this` prefix. `this` allows you to access all the methods, props, states declared in your class, it is the same principle of `this.state`.

If you want to export it to be consumed over your application, then create a file, for example `utils.js` and inside this file `export const currYear = () => ....`

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes in your code

You are getting a syntax error because you are defending the function with const also you need to define the date as a function

```
currYear = () => {
  var year = new Date().getFullYear();
  return year;
}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {

 currYear = () => {
      var year = new Date().getFullYear();
      return year;
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> {this.currYear()} </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

In order, if you want to use the function inside of the class render

```
render() {
  function currYear() {
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    return year;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {currYear()}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/jipkm1 unfortunately thats not working in my file. Reason i tell you i am using laravel with react. Where laravel is a back end and react js is a front end.


React prompt a error if you declare anything in function without const as undefined. :)

this all method i also know and tried it.

But without a const it takes it undefined.

Comment: currYear = () => { instead of this it should be function curryear()

Comment: @wontone_boys Where are you using this function? is it inside the class or inside render or it's outside the class?

Comment: it always comes inside the render but before return and inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

it is fix now with this way

in a syntax we are checking everything in two way

1. const
2. function

**@Liam** your code is absolutely correct but i change this little bit with this way so it look exactly perfect.

```
function currYear() {
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
 return year;
}

{currYear()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the function currYear() :

```
var year = (new Date).getFullYear();
```

And use {this.currYear()} (yes, you can)

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is declared outside of the class, it will not be accessible as a field of the class in question. To call the function `currYear` simply call

```
{currYear()}
```

without the leading `this`

Comment: :) its inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
function currYear() {
  let year = new Date().getFullYear();
  return year;
}

function currMonth() {
  let month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
  return month;
}
function currDate() {
  let date = new Date().getDate();
  return date;
}

function getNeedDate(separator = "", t) {
  return `${currYear() + t}${separator}${
    currMonth() < 10 ? `0${currMonth()}` : `${currMonth()}`
  }${separator}${currDate() < 10 ? `0${currDate()}` : `${currDate()}`}`;
}

const thisYearDate = getNeedDate("-", 0);
const lastYearDate = getNeedDate("-", -1);
const nextYearDate = getNeedDate("-", 1);
```

Comment: You may want to include a bit of an explanation to your code. it makes it more useful